# Beautifulsoup Python nested text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wanted obtain text "Some text" nested within tags like this:

```
<tr>
   <td>CME Globex</td>
   <td colspan="4">
   Some text
   <a target="_blank"" href="http://...>View Rollover Dates</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I could do something like `.findAll('tr')` first, `some_tr.findAll('td', colspan=4)` second and then `some_td.find(text=True)`. But is there a more efficient way to do this? Is there a way to keep traversing through the tags and finally find the text?

Comment: Do you want to obtain only the "Some text" part or all texts, including "CME Globex" and "View Rollover Dates"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XPath` expressions using `lxml`:

```
html = """<tr>
   <td>CME Globex</td>
   <td colspan="4">
   Some text
   <a target="_blank"" href="http://...">View Rollover Dates</a>
   </td>
</tr>"""

import lxml.html

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
print tree.xpath('//tr/td[@colspan="4"]/text()')
```

---

**not what you're after...**

Another way is maybe find the anchor that links to "View Rollover Dates" and take the preceding element...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for a in soup.find_all('a', text='View Rollover Dates'):
    print a.previous_element
```

Comment: But what if "View Rollover Dates" doesn't exist for some other html code. I was looking for something like traversing through the `tr` tag into `td`.

Comment: @MaxKim So you're just looking for a shorter way to write the logic you described... not "another way" of getting at the text...

Comment: A more efficient way to find text

Comment: IS there a way to go to the last tag, whether it be `td`, `a` , whatever and draw the text?

Comment: @MaxKim I don't understand what you mean by "draw the text"

Comment: by draw the text, I mean find it and print it or store it

Comment: If I knew that I was looking for text right after the `<td> CME Globex <\td>` tag, what would be best way to retrieve the text?

Comment: .find ('td', text='whatever') then similar to above @maxkim

Comment: so how you did `a.previous_elemet()`, I would do `a.next_element()`?

Comment: Or next elements depending how many you want to look ahead... @maxkim